# How increase the range of long long in C++?

Tags: c++, rsa

I am using dev C++ IDE to create a program to run the RSA algorithm. The algorithm, as is known, uses very large numbers. Numbers with 24-26 digits. The long long data types only supports upto 20 or so digits. How do I handle such huge numbers in C++? Is there a way I can change the limits/size/range of the long data type?

Comment: In the future we will have http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0_beta1/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html. I assume [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) already deals with all that somehow.

Comment: there are numerous big number libraries, e.g. gmp, have you tried googling for them?

Comment: @PlasmaHH expand that comment and make it an answer.

Comment: Use a big-number library. Nothing you really want to do will be intrinsic to the native types of most implementations (i.e. no one's `long long` is going to be long-enough). Something like the [BN library](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bn.html#) from OpenSSL, for example.

Comment: I'll try gmp and get back to you. How do I go about boost?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Please DO write that as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to popular request:

There are a lot of bignumber libraries (all serving a different audience). Examples are:

- gmp (or a better interface on top of it: mpfr)
- mpir (gmp fork)

Also the wikipedia article [Arbitrary precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) lists some. Google reveals even more.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a class or struct toencapsulation and may be like BigInt in java

> there's an example for you http://hi.baidu.com/lauo1988/item/ed31512ba601e8cddcf69adb

Comment: I'll go through the class and understand how it works, first. Thanks!